# Is it possible to auto rotate images in the photo widget?

Tags: qgis, widget, photos, exif, forms

If I use the photo widget in the default QGIS form images are not auto rotated according to their exif rotation.
Is there a way to show rotated images?

[image]

The correct way to display the image according the the exif rotation would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Which qgis version? This should work correctly in 3.x

Comment: @ndawson: It's 2.18.21. I just testet it in QGIS 3: there it works correctly. But we won't switch to QGIS 3.x in my company before QGIS 3.4 is out. Therefore I am looking for a way to show the images correctly rotated in QGIS 2.18.x. If it's not possible in QGIS core I will probably fork a plugin like https://github.com/KIOS-Research/ImportPhotos/ and implement the rotation.